# Erlang: gen_server in supervisor does not restart at the last known state

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server, erlang-supervisor

I'm working in Erlang with a supervisor that looks like this:

```
-module(a_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).

%% API
-export([start_link/0, init/1]).

start_link() ->
  supervisor:start_link({local,?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init(_Args) ->
  RestartStrategy = {simple_one_for_one, 5, 3600},
  ChildSpec = {
    a_gen_server,
    {a_gen_server, start_link, []},
    permanent,
    brutal_kill,
    worker,
    [a_gen_server]
  },
  {ok, {RestartStrategy,[ChildSpec]}}.
```

And a gen_server that looks like this:

```
-module(a_gen_server).
-behavior(gen_server).

%% API
-export([start_link/2, init/1]).

start_link(Name, {X, Y}) ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, Name}, ?MODULE, [Name, {X,Y}], []),
  ok.

init([Name, {X,Y}]) ->
  process_flag(trap_exit, true),
  io:format("~p: position {~p,~p}~n",[Name, X, Y]),
  {ok, {X,Y}}.

move(Name, {DestX, DestY}) ->
   gen_server:cast(Name, {move, {DestX, DestY}}).

handle_cast({move, {DestX, DestY}}, {X,Y}) ->
  {noreply, {DestX, DestY}}.
```

The `move(Name, {DestX, DestY})` basically moves the location of Name to the new position. Now when I initiate the supervisor and then gen_server and try to crash one of the child processes using `erlang:exit(Pid1, die).` the process crashes and restarts, as expected, but it starts at the original position where it was started initially (X,Y) instead of the last known position (DestX, DestY). I want to know if the gen_server can store the state in a way that when the process restarts, it resumes at the last known position instead of the original position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gen_server` itself has a *volatile* state, in the sense that (as you described in your question) it will go away once the server dies.
To preserve the state you will need to use some external mechanisms, such as:

- [an `ets` table](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) where you keep the state of all your servers indexed by… say… server name or something.
- [`persistent_term`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/persistent_term.html), again, indexing the information either in a very large map where the keys are the ids of your servers… or by using multiple terms, one per server.

But, if you end up using any of those solutions, it will now be worth considering if you need the servers at all. If their only responsibility is to manage some state… once that state is stored safely somewhere else, you might want to consider just managing it there directly instead of going through a server process to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for the details! I need the gen_server for a few other operations too, so if I can keep the state in an ets table in the supervisor, that should potentially work for me. But I can't figure out how to keep this state (because if let's say I initiate an ets table in supervisor init I can't access it in other methods), and how to make the gen_server restore the state from what is kept in the ets table in supervisor?

Comment: Hi @Brujo Benavides, I tried to work through your suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71352025/erlang-ets-table-does-not-persist-data-after-gen-server-crashes-and-restarts but using ets table like this doesn't seem to work for me either.